# Criar 2 elementos influenciando o mesmo CSS

Tags: css

É Possível criar um efeito em HOVER com dois elementos influenciando um em comum ?

por exemplo:

```
#div:hover "ou" #div2:hover = #elemento{display:block;}
```

Consegui ser claro ?

Comment: Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/7210)

Comment: Fico com a sensação que esse `#elemento` pode ser "ilegal". O que quero dizer é que não pode ter dois elementos diferentes com a mesma ID na mesma página. Se não fôr o caso ignore-me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu acho que entendi. Você pode definir um mesmo *set* para duas ou mais regras, separando-as com vírgulas:

```
#div:hover #elemento,
#div2:hover #elemento
{
    display:block;
}
```

Caso eu tenha entendido errado, sinta-se à vontade para adicionar mais informações à sua pergunta. =)

Comment: Legal, era exatamente essa minha dúvida..

Comment: @manzetti.denis se foi respondido corretamente como solicitação, teria como marcar como resposta correta para que outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema futuramente saibam a resposta correta para a pergunta ?

Comment: Não é uma boa prática, poderia ter feito a mesma coisa utilizando uma classe, mais adequada para mais de um elemento.

Comment: @MarceloAymone você está correto em sua análise, e é um comentário válido para o usuário produzir um código com maior qualidade. Entretanto, o ponto da resposta era demonstrar a aplicação de um mesmo set de regras para dois escopos.

Comment: @DouglasBernadino, eu respondi ali em cima. Sim, ele respondeu minha dúvida.